# SOAP API on Python

Tags: python, soap

I'm trying to call the Country capitals SOAP API to get the country capital on Python.

```
import requests
url = "http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL"
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
body = """<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ xmlns:web=http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:CapitalCity>
         <web:sCountryISOCode>USA</web:sCountryISOCode>
      </web:CapitalCity>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"""
response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

I get a 200 OK response but it doesn't return the actual country capital, instead it just returns the entire content from the browser when you visit this http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL

It works without issues on SoapUI, do you know what I'm doing wrong on python?

Comment: I don't know what SoapUI is, but I tried with the python `zeep` soap client and it worked for me. Running your code I got status 500. Crafting your own SOAP seems like a heavy lift to me.

Comment: Content-Type needs to be *application/soap+xml*. Also, remove *?WSDL* from the end of your URL

Comment: @BrutusForcus: Thanks, I did that but its still just returning the full browser data

Comment: @tdelaney: thanks. I tried using zeep now and now it returns "Country not found in the database". This is how I'm calling it. Is there any error in how i'm passing the xml?

`client = Client(wsdl_url)
result = client.service.CapitalCity(body)`

Comment: Body as in the soap doc above? Just the country name. `client.service.CapitalCity("USA")`.  SOAP is the transport, but its exposed as a regular API at the python level.

Comment: @tdelaney: However, it works if i do this:
`result = client.service.CapitalCity("USA")`

Im trying to find out how to pass the complete xml and still get the correct output

Comment: @tdelaney: okay so it seems like it wont work with the complete xml. Okay thanks a lot for your help. Im not sure how to mark your comment as correct though

Comment: SOAP uses a fairly complicated XML to build an interface spec and pass the payload for api calls. But you really don't need to do that yourself. Its supposed to be exposed as regular classes and functions at the high level. You should be able to replace backend with any number of transports like XMLRPC and still have your code look the same (except that first zeep.Client call).

Comment: The question was how to get the xml to work. I'll go ahead and answer as "let zeep do the xml". Maybe somebody will get your xml going too. I used to hand-craft SOAP when python SOAP clients were horrible. But now, well, now I don't use any SOAP APIs so its a moot point for me.

Answer (score 3):

A good SOAP client should build the XML for you. SOAP is a transport, like any of a dozen other Remote Procedure Call systems. One SOAP client is zeep. It reads the WSDL and builds a local client for you call. You can get the job done with

```
import zeep
url = "http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL"
client = zeep.Client(url)
print(client.service.CapitalCity("USA")
```

Let zeep do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

This works:-

```
import requests


xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <CapitalCity xmlns="http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo">
      <sCountryISOCode>USA</sCountryISOCode>
    </CapitalCity>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>"""
url = 'http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=xml)
    r.raise_for_status()
    print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **URL address of the service WSDL** is:
http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL
That's why you get the WSDL content instead of the response message.

The **URL address of the service endpoint** is specified within the WSDL and is:
http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso

If you utilize a SOAP library like zeep, you may initialize the client with the WSDL URL, however if you consume the SOAP service on your own (making an HTTP POST request), you need to use the endpoint address.